# Time calculation for time value entered in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I need help on calculating my time difference. I search on the forum but not what I need.  Here is the code I am using:-

```
    (convert(varchar(10),([RT_Phase_Time])-(convert(time,'00:30:00'))))
```

So I `[RT_Phase_Time]` is in this format `'hh:mm:ss'`.  I am trying to get the difference between `([RT_Phase_Time] - '00:30:00')`.  Please help!

Comment: Which are you using, mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can easily do that with TIMEDIFF().

```
TIMEDIFF('22:00:00','00:30:00');
-- Returns '21:30:00'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: I tried Timediff, it says TIMEDIFF is not built in function

Comment: Please make sure you don't have a space between TIMEDIFF and the parenthesis. TIMEDIFF ( won't work.

Comment: Still same issue. I am using a case statment like this.  Case RT_Phase_Time < 00:30:00 then TIMEDIFF([RT_Phase_Time],'00:30:00') end as timedifference

Comment: What mysql version you're running ? Check with the SQL: SELECT VERSION().

This function was added on MySQL 4.1.1, I doubt you're using a version older than that.

Comment: I think so is there any other way?

Comment: No way, you're not running MySQL then. Why did you tag sql server on the topic as well ? Are you running MySQL or SQL Server ?

Comment: I am running SQL server.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, check the BOL for datediff to convert to other values:

```
declare @rt_phase_time time
set @rt_phase_time = '12:30:30'

select datediff(ss,cast('00:30:00' as time),@rt_phase_time)
```

Comment: My phase_time is declared as varchar.  I need to convert this to time (hh:mm:ss) and then subtract time which I will be hardcoding in my sql.